# How to understand the use of the help method in Python to view the information and methods of the module?

Tags: python-2.7, dns

one example：

1. The A record of DNS

The example code for the A record of DNS in internet is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# @Time : 2017/10/1 9:58 
# @File : DNS.py 
# @Software: PyCharm
import dns.resolver
domain = input("Please input Domain name:")       
A = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'A')         
for i in A.response.answer:             
# print(i)              
    for j in i.items:                   
        print(j)
```

Here dns.resolver is a module, I can find the class of this module and the corresponding method according to "help>dns.resolver", such as its "query" method

I want to confirm the response.answer is dns.resolver method, find the following information:

```
  class Answer(__builtin__.object)

 |  DNS stub resolver answer

 |  

 |  Instances of this class bundle up the result of a successful DNS

 |  resolution.

 |  

 |  For convenience, the answer object implements much of the sequence

 |  protocol, forwarding to its rrset.  E.g. "for a in answer" is

 |  equivalent to "for a in answer.rrset", "answer" is equivalent

 |  to "answer.rrset", and "answer[i:j]" is equivalent to

 |  "answer.rrset[i:j]".

 |  

 |  Note that CNAMEs or DNAMEs in the response may mean that answer

 |  node's name might not be the query name.

 |  

 |  @ivar qname: The query name

 |  @type qname: dns.name.Name object

 |  @ivar rdtype: The query type

 |  @type rdtype: int

 |  @ivar rdclass: The query class

 |  @type rdclass: int

 |  @ivar response: The response message
 |  @type response: dns.message.Message object

 |  @ivar rrset: The answer

 |  @type rrset: dns.rrset.RRset object

 |  @ivar expiration: The time when the answer expires

 |  @type expiration: float (seconds since the epoch)

 |  @ivar canonical_name: The canonical name of the query name

 |  @type canonical_name: dns.name.Name object
```

First question:

The "answer" here is a class, so what do the following @ivar response and @type response mean? How to judge response.answer is a method?

Second question:

`A = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'A')`

Is A here an object? According to my understanding:

`Object = module. class()`

But the example format here is:

`A = module. method (parameter),`

Can such a format also generate an object?

Third question:

`A = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'A')`

If A here is an object, follow this line:

`for i in A.response.answer:`

A as an object, can I continue to use the module dns.resolver method "response.answer" on A, is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1:

> The "answer" here is a class, so what do the following @ivar response and @type response mean? How to judge response.answer is a method?

@ivar and @type are basically variable name and variable type respectively. 
This code is written properly. So to tell the user what each variable do and what is the type of each variable these are the conventions used by programmers.
you may also see sometimes @param @type @rtype @return etc.

For the second part, you can see

```
 @ivar response: The response message
 @type response: dns.message.Message object
```

which says that response variable is an object of dns.message.Message class.
So it will have some attributes and methods associated with it. For more info see the help of this class dns.message.Message.

Question 2:

> A = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'A')
>
> Is A here an object? According to my understanding:
>
> Object = module. class()
>
> But the example format here is:
>
> A = module. method (parameter),
>
> Can such a format also generate an object?

Everything is an object in python. 
 For  Object = module. class() 
Its not necessary always, you can have methods/functions to create an object of class.

Basically any function definition will create a new object of some type. e.g

```
def sum():
    return 10
```

This simple function also creates an object of int type. Now you can modify the arguments/definition to get back specific sort of objects.

For your case, when we have some application with server connections/database connections/ web connection apis etc. We have two entity per say.

1. Connection request
2. Connection Response

Say for example you send a GET request to a server,  and the server responds back with 200 OK(connection successful). Your GET request will be connection request and 200 OK is connection response.
While programming this sort of behavior,  we generally have a request method which will return me an object of Response class.

Third Question:

> A = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'A')
>
> If A here is an object, follow this line:
>
> for i in A.response.answer:
>
> A as an object, can I continue to use the module dns.resolver method
>   "response.answer" on A, is my understanding correct?

Yes, if response.answer is an method associated with A, you can certainly use it.